# Error installing rubyMine, no SDK specified, but it is listed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sdk, rubygems, rubymine

Getting "Could not install gems:no SDK specified" when trying to run any command such as starting the rails server.  Why am I getting this and how can I get around it?
I've had issues before with the JDK but not seen this SDK error.

[image]

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I went into settings and an SDK was already listed, but it wasn't until I clicked 'update gems' that everything got installed ok.  Then I was able to start and use the application fine.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I tried following the advice in the above two answers and it still did not work for me.
After making sure my project passed all rSpec I gave up on RubyMine and simply zapped the .idea sub-directory and got it to work after I recreated the RubyMine project from scratch.

Hope this helps.

p.s. my env is Mac Os X with RVM installed. Maybe something confused RubyMine with all that.

Answer (score 2):

I succeeded after I restarted Rubymine.