# Rubymine shows: No SDK specified

Tags: ruby, rubymine

I have installed Rubymine 1.9.3 in my mac.When I run a project I get a message that " No SDK specified " .I am  not sure how to get rid of this error.Could someone help me please ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error installing rubyMine, no SDK specified, but it is listed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10942348/error-installing-rubymine-no-sdk-specified-but-it-is-listed)

Comment: do you use something like rvm, rbevn, chruby? rubymine only supports rvm by default, even then sometimes you need to switch the ruby environment manually from the project settings.

Answer (score 3):

rubymine window > help > find actions > sdk, or file > settings > search sdk, you can set sdk here(sdk is ruby_dir/bin/ruby, in linux, you can use `which ruby` to find